# Not finding why output to TextView is NaN

Tags: android

I've been trying for some days now to figure out why I am not getting a proper output from my app. No errors are showing up in logcat to explain why the output is "NaN" and not the value I'm attempting o calculate. Could someone show me the mistake(s) that I've made? It's a calculator app for my final year school project and I've tried to rectify the issue albeit without much success.

Here is the Main class for the app.

I've tried pretty much anything that has been suggested in various forums for similar issues.

```
public String educationStr, ethnicity, ldlStr, hdlStr, ageStr, tcStr, sysBPStr, diaBPStr;
public int married=0, education=0, educationSec=0, educationTert=0;
public int smoker=0, ethnicityChk=0;
public int highCholesterol=0;
public int atrialFibrillation=0;
public int familialCVD=0;
public int hypertension=0;
public int sex=0;
public int age=0;
public double tcVal = 0;
public double hdlVal=0;
public double ldlVal = 0;
public int sysBPval = 0;
public int diaBPval = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_calculator);

    //spinner for sex choices
    Spinner spinnerSex = findViewById(R.id.sexSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSex = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SexChoices, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSex.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSex.setAdapter(adapterSex);
    spinnerSex.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for marriage choices
    Spinner spinnerMarried = findViewById(R.id.marriedSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMarried = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.YN, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterMarried.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerMarried.setAdapter(adapterMarried);
    spinnerMarried.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for Ethnicity
    Spinner spinnerEthnicity = findViewById(R.id.ethnicitySelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterEthnicity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.EthnicChoices, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterEthnicity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerEthnicity.setAdapter(adapterEthnicity);
    spinnerEthnicity.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for education
    Spinner spinnerEducation = findViewById(R.id.EduLevelSpin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterEducation = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.EduLevel, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterEducation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerEducation.setAdapter(adapterEducation);
    spinnerEducation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for smoking history
    Spinner spinnerSmoker = findViewById(R.id.smokerSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSmoker = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.smoke, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSmoker.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSmoker.setAdapter(adapterSmoker);
    spinnerSmoker.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for family health --> high cholesterol
    Spinner spinnerHighCholesterol = findViewById(R.id.highCholesterolSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterHighCholesterol = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.YN, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterHighCholesterol.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerHighCholesterol.setAdapter(adapterHighCholesterol);
    spinnerHighCholesterol.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for family health --> A Fib
    Spinner spinnerAFib = findViewById(R.id.atrialFibrillationSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterAFib = 
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.YN, simple_spinner_item);
    adapterAFib.setDropDownViewResource
(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown 
 item);
    spinnerAFib.setAdapter(adapterAFib);
    spinnerAFib.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for family health --> Hypertension
    Spinner spinnerHypertension = findViewById(R.id.HBPSpinSelect);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterHypertension = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.YN, 
    simple_spinner_item);


   adapterHypertension.setDropDownViewResource
  (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerHypertension.setAdapter(adapterHypertension);
    spinnerHypertension.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //spinner for family health --> Hypertension
    Spinner spinnerFamilialCVD = findViewById(R.id.familialCVDSpin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterFamilialCVD = 
   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.YN, 
   simple_spinner_item);
    adapterFamilialCVD.setDropDownViewResource
   (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFamilialCVD.setAdapter(adapterFamilialCVD);
    spinnerFamilialCVD.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    //declaring button
    final Button BtnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveNsend);

    BtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.ageEnter:
                    EditText enterAge = findViewById(R.id.ageEnter);
                    ageStr = enterAge.getText().toString();
                    age = Integer.valueOf(ageStr);
                    break;

                case R.id.sysBPEnter:
                    EditText enterSys = findViewById(R.id.sysBPEnter);
                    sysBPStr = enterSys.getText().toString();
                    sysBPval = Integer.valueOf(sysBPStr);
                    break;

                case R.id.diaBPEnter:
                    EditText enterDia = findViewById(R.id.diaBPEnter);
                    diaBPStr = enterDia.getText().toString();
                    diaBPval = Integer.valueOf(diaBPStr);
                    break;

                case R.id.tcEnter:
                    EditText enterTC = findViewById(R.id.tcEnter);
                    tcStr = enterTC.getText().toString();
                    tcVal = Integer.valueOf(tcStr);
                    break;

                case R.id.hdlEnter:
                    EditText enterHDL = findViewById(R.id.hdlEnter);
                    hdlStr = enterHDL.getText().toString();
                    hdlVal = Integer.valueOf(hdlStr);
                    break;

                case R.id.ldlEnter:
                    EditText enterLDL = findViewById(R.id.ldlEnter);
                    ldlStr = enterLDL.getText().toString();
                    ldlVal = Integer.valueOf(ldlStr);
            }

            if (ethnicityChk == 1){

                Intent RiskCalc1 = new 
         Intent(getApplicationContext(),displayLinRiskResult.class);
                startActivity(RiskCalc1);

            } else if (ethnicityChk == 2){

                Intent RiskCalc2 = new 
    Intent(getApplicationContext(),displayDiscrimRiskResult.class);
                startActivity(RiskCalc2);

            }

        }

    });

}

  @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> 
        adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    switch(adapterView.getId()){
        case R.id.sexSelect:
            String sexStr = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (sexStr.equalsIgnoreCase("female")){
                sex = 1;
            }
            else if (sexStr.equalsIgnoreCase("male")){
                sex = 0;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), sex, 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.marriedSelect:
            String marriedStr = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (marriedStr.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                married = 1;
            }
            else if (marriedStr.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                married = 0;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), married, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.smokerSelect:
            String smokerStr = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (ethnicity.equalsIgnoreCase("Afro-Caribbean"))
                {if (smokerStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Smoker")){
                    smoker = 1;
                }
                else if (smokerStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Non-smoker")){
                    smoker = 0;
                } }
            else if (ethnicity.equalsIgnoreCase("Mixed-Caribbean")){
            {if (smokerStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Smoker")){
                smoker = 0;
            }
            else if (smokerStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Ex-smoker")){
                smoker = 1;
            } }}
            // Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), smokerStr, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        case R.id.ethnicitySelect:
            ethnicity = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            if (ethnicity.equals("Afro-Caribbean")|| 
        (ethnicity.equals("Indo-Caribbean"))){
                ethnicityChk = 1;
            }
            else if (ethnicity.equals("Mixed-Caribbean")){
                ethnicityChk = 2;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), ethnicityStr, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        case R.id.EduLevelSpin:
            educationStr = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),education, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            if (educationStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Secondary")){
                educationSec = 1;
                educationTert = 0;
                education = 1;
            }
            else if (educationStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Tertiary")){
                educationSec = 1;
                educationTert = 1;
                education = 1;
            }
            else {
                education = 1;
                educationSec = 0;
                educationTert = 0;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.highCholesterolSelect:
            String highCholesterolStr = (String) 
        adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            if (highCholesterolStr.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                highCholesterol = 1;
            }
            else if (highCholesterolStr.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                highCholesterol = 0;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),
            highCholesterolStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        case R.id.atrialFibrillationSelect:
            String AfibStr = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            if (AfibStr.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                atrialFibrillation = 1;
            }
            else if (AfibStr.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                atrialFibrillation = 0;
            }
            // Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), 
           AfibStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        case R.id.HBPSpinSelect:
            String HBPstr = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            if (HBPstr.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                hypertension = 1;
            }
            else if (HBPstr.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                hypertension = 0;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), 
           HBPstring,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        case R.id.familialCVDSpin:
            String famCVDStr = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
            if (famCVDStr.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                familialCVD = 1;
            }
            else if (famCVDStr.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                familialCVD = 0;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), 
    famCVDString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

    }



}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Here is the class used to output the result:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_lin_risk);

        TextView RiskViewLinRisk = findViewById(R.id.RiskViewLinRisk);

        float LinRisk = (float) ((-16.13) + (0.119 * age) - (1.333 * sex) 
        + (1.502 * married) + (2.619 * smoker) - (0.555 * (tcVal / 
         hdlVal)) + (0.026 *ldlVal) + (1.952 * highCholesterol) + (2.867 
        * atrialFibrillation) + (4.272 * hypertension) + (1.957 * 
        familialCVD));

        String LinRiskStr = Float.toString(LinRisk);


        RiskViewLinRisk.setText(LinRiskStr);
    }
```

Comment: you did not mention the issue/error you are facing

Comment: no error showing up in logcat...my text output just shows NaN instead of the value I'm trying to calculate

Comment: try `String.valueOf(LinRisk);` instead of `Float.toString(LinRisk);`, a float is NaN when its not get Initialise with a valid float value

Comment: The only place I can see that there could be a problem is in `tcVal / hdlVal`. They're both doubles and 0 at the beginning. In Java, dividing double 0 by double 0 results in not a number - NaN. To check if this is the case, set temporarly `hdlVal` to 1 and let us know, so we can suggest a solution.

Comment: @Fred...worked like a charm..countless hours combing over this code just for this simple mistake...thanks much for the help

Comment: another issue that popped up is that the equation is only using the initialized values of the variables and not what I was setting the variables to.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a bit more context than in the comments, double division in Java can return a `NaN` which stands for "not a number". This  happens when you divide 0.0 by 0.0, but can also happen if you take the square root of a negative number.

Because Java implements the IEEE standard for NaN, it guarantees that NaN is never equal to itself. In fact, the only comparison that returns true is `NaN != NaN`. There's a very famous puzzle:

```
float x = //...
if (x != x)
   System.out.println("Foo");
```

The question is "initialize `x` to a value which guarantees that Foo is printed". The answer is `Float.NaN`, because NaN is not equal to itself. Also, this is the only value that could work. All other values in Java would not solve this puzzle.

For this reason, a solution used lots of times to identify if a number is NaN is:

```
public boolean isNan(float x) {
    return x != x;
}
```

(Since Java 8 a method exists in the standard lib to verify if a number is NaN)

You could use this to check the result of the division you're doing and avoid displaying NaN when you don't want to.

To display the values after you click on the button you have to run again the calculation and display it. I recommend extracting it into a method:

```
public float calculateLinRisk() {
  return (float) ((-16.13) + (0.119 * age) - (1.333 * sex) 
    + (1.502 * married) + (2.619 * smoker) - (0.555 * (tcVal / 
     hdlVal)) + (0.026 *ldlVal) + (1.952 * highCholesterol) + (2.867 
    * atrialFibrillation) + (4.272 * hypertension) + (1.957 * 
    familialCVD));
}

public void displayCurrentLinRisk() {
    // This can also be a field in the main activity to 
    // avoid multiple calls to findViewById
    TextView RiskViewLinRisk = findViewById(R.id.RiskViewLinRisk);

    float LinRisk = calculateLinRisk()
    String LinRiskStr = Float.toString(LinRisk);

    RiskViewLinRisk.setText(LinRiskStr);
}
```

`onCreate` becomes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_lin_risk);

    displayCurrentLinRisk();
}
```

Then you can use this at the end of click listener

```
BtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // ...
      displayCurrentLinRisk();
    }
}
```

Comment: would this help with the initialization issue I'm getting? The formula is only taking the values i initialized and not accepting the values input into those same variables during app execution.